# Load FXML and add existing controller

Tags: javafx, controller

In my LogonWindow I have  2 AnchorPane (visible one of them)
In the first one : I put LogonForm.fxml
In the second one : I put RegisterForm.fxml

I have both instance of Controller in LogonWindowController. 
When register button is clicked int the second AnchorPane I put RegisterConfirm.fxml and I set LogonForm visible.

And now when I click once again to  set RegisterVisible I must reload FXML.  But I don't want to create a new instance of Controller.
In other cases pareil I would like to reload FXML and use an existing Controller

I was trying this solution :

```
AnchorPane rootPane;
MyController controller = new MyController();
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("my.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setRoot(rootPane);
fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
fxmlLoader.load();
```

But I have this message

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Volumes/Studia/Programowanie/Projekty/GIT-REPOSITORY/GenealogyTreeJAVAFX/GenealogyTreeClientFX/target/classes/com/genealogytree/application/fxml/RegisterForm.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at com.genealogytree.application.ScreenManager.reloadFxml(ScreenManager.java:175)
    at com.genealogytree.application.fxmlcontrollers.LogonWindowController.loadRegisterForm(LogonWindowController.java:130)
    at com.genealogytree.application.fxmlcontrollers.LogonFormController.openRegisterForm(LogonFormController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Hyperlink.java:153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.setValue(ObjectProperty.java:69)
    at com.genealogytree.application.fxmlcontrollers.RegisterFormController.initialize(RegisterFormController.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 60 more
```

The bound value :

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    LOG.info("Initialisation " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":  " + this.toString());
    this.languageBundle.setValue(rb);
}
```

Comment: You obviously did bind `languageBundle` somewhere. What effect should that code have instead???

Comment: What's the actual question here? Obviously you must be binding `languageBundle` somewhere. You can't set a bound value (because that would violate the binding). When `initialize` is called a second time (just think for a moment about whether that is a good idea), you try to set something that's bound. So you get an error. The bottom line here is that you should have a one-to-one relationship between root elements created by the FXML, and controllers. So either you should not be reloading the FXML, or you should not be using the same controller instance.

Comment: Yes. the languageBundle is bind to LanguageBundle from my ContextBean.  I was implemented internalization. The text properties listen languageBean. And when I change Language. I change text property. So  what can I do ??

Comment: Or.. How can I verify which controller is set to an AnchorPane ??   When I use getClass I received only that is AnchorPane